# CakePHP, How to update an entity with an entity

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to patch an entity with an entity. Is there a way to do this easily using cakephp? fields with same value ignore then update just fields with change of values

```
//$fooEntityExisting->name = 'hi';
//$fooEntityNew->name = 'hello';
public function updEntWithEnt($fooEntityExisting, $fooEntityNew) {
   // update here
   $fooEntityExisting->set('name', $fooEntityNew->get('name'));
   return $fooEntityNew
}
```

Comment: Can you simply use `$fooEntityExisting->toArray()` to get it in array formay and pass that to `patchEntity`? The patch function will inherently ignore fields that match.

Comment: *format*, not *formay*. Why can I edit other people's questions, but not my own comments? :-( (I know I can if I do it quickly, but I didn't notice until too late.)

Comment: I see, I'll try doing that.so the syntax would likely be $fooEntityExisting->patchEntity($fooEntityNewArrayed); ?

Comment: `patchEntity` is a function of the *table* object, not the entity. It's well documented.

Comment: ow right, sorry, should be fooTable->patchEntity($fooEntityExisting, $fooEntityNew)?

Comment: `fooTable->patchEntity($fooEntityExisting, $fooEntityNew->toArray())`

Comment: i see, so you can make it toArray() so it has the same data format for $this->request->getData(); Thanks!

Comment: Yes. The second parameter to `patchEntity` must be an array. `$this->request->getData` returns an array, so does `$entity->toArray`.